How is this data in this KQL query not converting properly?
I set up a custom metric with the steps from this link:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/agents/data-collection-log-text?tabs=portal
It works to a degree. I get the data in log analytics that was taken from a text file on a dhcp server.
The problem is I can't convert the strings to int within KQL. When converting it, it appears blank in the column. With gettype() on it, it says string. tostring also will display the number as a string, but toint, tolong, it all appears blank. I tried toint(tostring(Free)) as well. Is there any alternative way to convert the value? After the cast, I do a gettype() on the blank one, and it is int, there's just nothing there.

Tried converting string to INT and expected INT but it was blank
--
Powershell code to create a text file that is then ingested by Azure Monitor via a DCE with 'custom text log'
$DHCP_stats = Get-DhcpServerv4ScopeStatistics

$DHCP_stats_string = (Get-Date).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")  +"," + $DHCP_stats.ScopeId.ToString() + "," + $DHCP_stats.Free.ToString() + "," + $DHCP_stats.InUse.ToString() + "," + ($DHCP_stats.PercentageInUse.ToString()).SubString(0,($DHCP_stats.PercentageInUse.ToString()).IndexOf(".")+2) + "," + $DHCP_stats.Reserved.ToString()
$DHCP_stats_string >> "C:\Logs\DHCP_Scope_Usage.txt"

It's just a text file that is ingested into log analytics. Desired output is numbers are int, so I can make pie charts and different visualizations

Can you provide how your input table looks? and your desired output too.

I added the info. It's just a standard text file I created in powershell that is automatically generated on the dhcp server. Monitor agent then grabs it, and I have the data in log analytics

It depends on how the custom log is ingested and how Azure Monitor parses it. By cleaning the data with trim() and verifying the type with gettype(), you can resolve the blank column issue. Please check below links for reference.
To check for hidden characters
DHCP_Scope_Usage_CL
| project Free, In_Use
| extend FreeLength = strlen(Free), In_UseLength = strlen(In_Use)


To trim any unwanted characters
DHCP_Scope_Usage_CL
| project Free, In_Use
| extend Cleaned_Free = trim(" ", Free)
| extend Free_Int = toint(Cleaned_Free)


To verify if the data is actually being converted to integers
DHCP_Scope_Usage_CL
| project Free, In_Use
| extend Free_Int = toint(trim(" ", Free))
| extend DataType = gettype(Free_Int)


After you have created the Log Analytics workspace

and the Data Collection Rule (DCR) for collecting DHCP logs

the next step is to associate the DCR with a resource, such as a virtual machine or network interface, to start collecting the logs.
az monitor data-collection rule association create \
  --name "dhcp-vm-dcr-association" \
  --rule-id "/subscriptions/abcd-efg-hijk-lmnop-9dcy/resourceGroups/arkorg/providers/Microsoft.Insights/dataCollectionRules/DHCPLogDCR" \
  --resource "/subscriptions/abcd-efg-hijk-lmnop-9dcy/resourceGroups/arkorg/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/myDHCPvm"


you can verify if the logs are being ingested in your Log Analytics.
